# Linking structures in c

Tags: c, list, struct, linker

I have three structures and I need to link them. My structures are:

```
struct Product{
    int IdOfProduct;
    char *NameOfProduct;
    char *CategoryOfProduct;
    int PriceOfProduct;
    struct Product *NextPtr;
};

struct Customer{
int IdOfCustomer;
char *NameOfCustomer;
char *SurnameOfCustomer;
struct Basket *ListOfBasket;
struct Customer *NextPtr;}*Header=NULL;

struct Basket{
int IdOfBasket;
struct Product *ProductList;
int AmountOfTotal;
struct Basket *NextPtr;};
```

I have basket txt and it is: [basket txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbZlZ.png)
customer id basket id and product id respectively. I write a function to read txt:

```
int ReadBasket(){
FILE *ListOfBasket;
int CustomerIdInBasket;
int BasketIdInBasket;
int ProductIdInBasket;
struct Customer *Temp=NULL,*Head=NULL;
struct Customer *TempCustomer;
TempCustomer= Header;
TempCustomer = (struct Customer *)malloc(sizeof(struct Customer));
ListOfBasket = fopen("basket.txt","r");
while(fscanf(ListOfBasket,"%d\t%d\t%d",&CustomerIdInBasket,&BasketIdInBasket,&ProductIdInBasket)==3)
{

    while(TempCustomer->IdOfCustomer!=CustomerIdInBasket)
    {
    TempCustomer->IdOfCustomer=CustomerIdInBasket;
    TempCustomer->ListOfBasket->IdOfBasket=BasketIdInBasket;
    TempCustomer->ListOfBasket->ProductList->IdOfProduct=ProductIdInBasket;
    TempCustomer=TempCustomer->NextPtr;
    }
```

but I have an error that is project.exe has stopped working. What is my mistake?

Comment: A lot of mistake in this code. I think you need to read again how works linked list. You forget to allocate memory for member of `TempCustomer`; you get pointer to next customer, but no allocation of memory; you never check if your pointer is set or not; you don't initialize member;....

Comment: Please be more specific. Explanations as "I have an error that is project.exe has stopped working" are not very helpful. And posting an image of a text rather than posting the text itself isn't helpful either.

Comment: Run your program under a Debugger and you will see where it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You forget some `malloc` :

```
 TempCustomer->ListOfBasket = malloc(sizeof(struct Basket));
 ....
 TempCustomer->ListOfBasket->ProductList = malloc(sizeof(struct Product));
```

But this fix only solves first iteration of second `while`. In this second while, it's not really clear what you do : you should probably create a new element (customer or product according information from file) and add it to a list. First you have to find if customer exists already. If not, create it (*ie* allocate memory **and** initialize it) and add it to linked list. And after, add a product to list of this customer.

In more general scope, your algorithm isn't correct : Only allocation of one customer, iteration over a linked list not initialized and without check if next element exists, add elements without reading file, ....

So before re-writing your code, I encourage you to *read again* how works linked list and to try with a simple linked list, which doesn't contain a linked list inside! You will find a lot of tutorials on internet to do that